# Graphql Mutation query for DynamoDB table having Custom Type attribute

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

Need help in Graphql Appsync

Appsync Custom Type :

```
type Employee {
        id: ID!
        name: String
        experiences: [Experiences]
        projects: [Projects]
}

Dynamo DB table Employee

Table: Employee
{
    id:’’,
    name:’’,
    experience:[
        {
            company:’’,
            from:’’,
            till:’’
        },
        {
            company:’’,
            from:’’,
            till:’’
        }
    ],
    projects:[

        {
            title:’’,
            date:’’

        },
        {
            title:’’,
            date:’’

         },
    ]

}
```

We need to update experience & Projects in 2 different mutation queries but update should be done in same dynamodb table.
Here are my doubts:

- Do need to create separate dynamodb table for Projects & Experience.
  How to write mutation queries for  this  table updating Projects &
  experience in diff mutation ?

Answer (score 1):

let me try and answer your questions:

> We need to update experience & Projects in 2 different mutation queries but update should be done in same dynamodb table.

You can create a single DataSource in AppSync, and have 2 mutations that resolve against this DataSource. This way, your mutations accept an array of Experience or Project types, and your resolver takes care of writing into this DynamoDB DataSource.

> Do need to create separate dynamodb table for Projects & Experience.

This really depends on your usecase. Having separate DynamoDB tables helps you fetch the [1:N] related types using secondary indexes. Separate tables also help you paginate the related types instead of fetching all dependencies in a single call. If you end up using a single table to store Employee/Projects/Experience, refer to the [Lists and Maps types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html#using-lists-and-maps) section in the DynamoDB resolver.

> How to write mutation queries for this table updating Projects & experience in diff mutation?

Like I mentioned, you would just define 2 mutations in your Schema that accept a list of types. In the resolver, you would write to appropriate tables. Please refer to the [following documentation on DynamoDB Resolvers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html#modifying-the-updatepost-resolver-dynamodb-updateitem) in AppSync.

Alternatively, you can also make use of [DynamoDB Batch Resolver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html#multi-table-batch) to write data into multiple tables.